# Generate random number from Bates distribution

Tags: python, simulation

Briefly introducing that Bates distribution is defined as the average random numbers from a uniform distribution.

The problem that I face is generating random numbers from Bates distribution with large m and n.

The time is consumed (very slow) when utilizing large m and n (such as m=10000 and n=10000000) while I just generate random numbers directly using simulating random numbers from uniform distribution and then taking the mean of those.

The python code is as follows

```
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (m, n)) 
bates_random_numbers = [np.mean(a[i]) for i in range(m)]
```

where m is the number of samples and n is the sample size

Is there any chance that we can generate random numbers from Bates distribution avoiding simulating uniform distribution directly?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Check out inverse transform sampling.

Comment: Have you considered using a normal approximation?  With such a large value of `n`, that distribution will be extremely close to a normal distribution with mean 0.5 and variance 1/(12*n).

Comment: I agree with @Warren Weckesser's use of the normal approximation, but if you absolutely must have a Bate's distribution, TensorFlow provides this: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Bates

Comment: Thanks for @iohans reply, yeah, I tried to check the inverse of cdf before. However, there is another problem of integrating the sum thing..., resulting fail.

Comment: That is the optional solution that I would take. I still want to use the exact random numbers from Bates distribution. Thanks for @WarrenWeckesser reply!

Comment: Thanks for @DamianSatterthwaite-Phillips reply!!! Yes!! I take your suggestion and eventually generate the random numbers from Bates distribution with TensorFlow. Thanks all your guys' help.

Comment: FYI: You can replace `[np.mean(a[i]) for i in range(m)]` with `a.mean(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

With TensorFlow, the code for generating random numbers from Bates distribution can be easily written as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# For example
m = 10000 # m is the number of samples

n1, n2 = 50, 100000 # n1, n2 are the number of used uniform distribution [0, 1] respectively

a = np.array(tfp.distributions.Bates(total_count=[n1, n2]).sample(m))
transposed = [list(i) for i in zip(*a)]

# Then we have the final two lists of random numbers from Bates distribution with n1 and n2.
bates_random_numbers_n1 = transposed[0] 
bates_random_numbers_n2 = transposed[1]
```